# From body null value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, binding, model-binding

I made this ajax call

```
 var value = $("#newval").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "Put",
        url: "/api/updateparameter/" + global_id,
        data: value,
        success: function () { HidePopUp(); }
    });
```

to this service :

```
        [HttpPut]
        [Authorize(Roles = "superadmin,admin")]
        [Route("updateparameter/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateConfiguration(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
            ajt_configuration obj = repoConfiguration.FindById(id);
            if (obj == null) return Ok();
            obj.value = value.ToString();
            repoConfiguration.UpdateConfiguration(obj.key, obj.value);
            return Ok();
        }
```

The problem is that `value` is always null in the service !!

So I need to know :

1. What it takes null as value?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the content type of the value on the client?

Comment: @PhilB it is a string type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't send the object to your service properly, you should define an object of key/value pairs that contains name and value of your variables.so you should change your ajax request like this:

```
var value = $("#newval").val(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "Put",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/api/updateparameter/" + global_id,
    data: {'value': value},
    success: function () { HidePopUp(); }
});
```